# MySQL: Cannot add foriegn key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Here are the 2 tables. The error comes at the last two lines of the table "Medical_Record":

```
CREATE TABLE Medical_Record(
Patient_SSN VARCHAR(10),
Record_ID VARCHAR(10),
Medical_Issue VARCHAR(45),
Medical_Status VARCHAR(15),
Doctor_ID VARCHAR(10),
Hosp_ID VARCHAR(10),
Event_Date DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (Patient_SSN,Record_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Patient_SSN) REFERENCES Citizen(SSN) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (Doctor_ID,Hosp_ID) REFERENCES Employment_Status(Worker_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
);

CREATE TABLE Employment_Status(
Citizen_SSN VARCHAR(10),
Worker_ID VARCHAR(10),
Org_ID VARCHAR(10),
Employee_Position VARCHAR(15),
Join_Date DATE,
Leave_Date DATE,
Profession VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY (Citizen_SSN,Worker_ID,Org_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Citizen_SSN) REFERENCES Citizen(SSN) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (Org_ID) REFERENCES Organization(Org_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Citizen(
SSN VARCHAR(10),
FName VARCHAR(15),
MName VARCHAR(15),
LName VARCHAR(15),
Gender VARCHAR(1),
Birth_Date DATE,
Death_Date DATE,
Spouse_SSN VARCHAR(10),
Blood_Group VARCHAR(5),
Pincode VARCHAR(7),
Address TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (SSN),
FOREIGN KEY (Spouse_SSN) REFERENCES Citizen(SSN) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Organization(
Org_ID VARCHAR(10),
Org_Name VARCHAR(45),
Email VARCHAR(45),
Phone_Number VARCHAR(15),
Established_Date DATE,
Closing_Date DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (Org_ID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update1**:
Attached below is the actual error executing your sql script.

[image]

You have a composite key defined in `Employee_Status` table.
Define individual key per column and then refer in the child table.
And it should be working.

```
PRIMARY KEY (Citizen_SSN,Worker_ID,Org_ID),
KEY (Worker_ID),  -- <-------- Add this line
KEY (Org_ID),  -- <-------- Add this line
```

**Original Answer**:
Every referenced parent field must have defined `index` on it. That is a condition for foreign key addition.

As per documentation on foreign key constraints:

> ```
> REFERENCES parent_tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
> ```

Define relevant *keys* on columns `Employment_Status.Worker_ID` and `Employment_Status.Org_ID`. Then you should be able to refer them in child table.

**Refer to**:

- [**MySQL Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
>       [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
>       REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
>       [ON DELETE reference_option]
>       [ON UPDATE reference_option]
>
> reference_option:
>       RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION

Comment: That doesn't work as well. I have already made an EER and try to forward engineer the diagram from MySQL Workbench and that gave me the same error.

Comment: You better add exact error statement thrown to your post.

Comment: Can you check `Citizen` and `Organization` tables as well.

Comment: Edited and added into the question. I have checked it thoroughly, nothing seems to be unusual. Can you try creating the same in your pc and check?

Comment: Thank You, However, I want to refer Doctor_ID and Hosp_ID together for a same row, so should I use KEY(Doctor_ID,Hosp_ID) or the one you suggested?